# array_push overwriting previously created object PHP

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create an array of objects which I can then display, the objects being created when a form has been submitted.

The first object gets successfully added, but when I add another object, it simply overwrites the last created object. Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

```
<?php require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/classes/Goal.php'; ?>
<?php require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/global/head.php'; ?>
<?php require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/config/init.php'; ?>

<?php

$input['title'] = "";
$input['deadline'] = "";
$input['description'] = "";

if(!isset($_SESSION['goals'])) {$_SESSION['goals'] = array();}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$_SESSION['goalCount'] ++;

$input['title'] = htmlentities($_POST ['title'],ENT_QUOTES);
$input['deadline'] = htmlentities($_POST ['deadline'],ENT_QUOTES);
$input['description'] = htmlentities($_POST ['description'],ENT_QUOTES);
convertDate($input['deadline']);


${'goal'. $_SESSION['goalCount']} = new Goal($input['title'], $input['description'], $_SESSION['username'], $input['deadline']);
array_push($_SESSION['goals'], ${'goal'. $_SESSION['goalCount']});

?>



<div class="top">
    <p>h</p>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="sixteen columns topbar">
        <?php require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/global/header.php'; ?><!-- Content Begins -->
        <div class="content">

        <h1> OO Test Page - Batch add goals</h1><hr/>

        <div class="six columns">

        <form action="" method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <div>
                <h4>Title</h4>
                    <span id='title-result'></span>
                    <label for="title"></label><br />
                    <input type="text" id="title" name="title" placeholder="e.g. Graduate" value="" required  aria-required="true">

                </div>
                <div>
                <h4>Description</h4>
                <span id='description-result'></span>
                    <label for="description"></label>


                    <textarea type="description" id="description" placeholder="e.g. with first-class honours" name="description" value="" required aria-required="true"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div>
                <h4>Deadline</h4>
                <span id='description-result'></span>
                    <label for="deadline"></label>
                    <input rows="2"type="date" id="datepick" placeholder="" name="deadline" value="" required aria-required="true"/>

                </div>

                <div class="submit">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add">
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form></div>


    <div class="ten columns">
    <?php


    foreach ($_SESSION['goals'] as $goal) 
    {
        echo '<div class="goal"><h4>'. $goal->title .'</h4>'. $goal->desc .'</h4><p>'. $goalCount .'</p></div>';
    }

    echo Goal::$counter;
    var_dump($_SESSION['goals'])

    ?>
    </div>
</div>

            <!-- Content Ends -->
        <?php require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/global/footer.php'; ?>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you define `$_SESSION['goals']` as array initially?

Comment: why not just push it normally, and add that count inside that array.

Comment: Yes at the top. Just as $_SESSION['goals']; to try not overwrite it

Comment: Is the session started with `session_start()`? If not, you'll keep writing the first element of `$_SESSION['goals']`.  By the way, I don't see a good reason here for the complicated variable variable `${'goal'.$_SESSION['goalCount']}`.  You could just instantiate that object directly into the  session array:  `$_SESSION['goals'][] = new Goal($input....);` instead of `array_push()`.

Comment: @Ghost How do you mean?

Comment: how are you tracking sessions? You need to do extra work to use the $_SESSION variable, and make sure php is configured properly. http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php

Comment: @Phillip-Marsden - I think Ghost means something like:  `$_SESSION['goals'][$_SESSION['goalCount'] = new Goal...`

Comment: @Phillip-Marsden Ah, but if you initialize `$_SESSION['goals']` as an array, unless you have it in conditional logic to only initialize if not already, you will be re-initializing it on each script load, and continuously overwriting it. Post that code for context please.

Comment: i'm just wondering why do you need to set it like this `${'goal'. $_SESSION['goalCount']}`, but anyways, there is still some missing pieces on your question, put some codes where you initialized that session

Comment: @Ghost I have included the whole page contents, if there is a better way to achieve this please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply initialize that session variables that you need. And no need to use variable variables and using it as a counter to push inside. Just normally push those object inside the session.

Example:

```
<?php require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/classes/Goal.php'; ?>
<?php require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/global/head.php'; ?>
<?php require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/config/init.php'; ?>
<?php

if(!isset($_SESSION['goals'], $_SESSION['goalCount'])) {
    $_SESSION['goals'] = array();
    $_SESSION['goalCount'] = 0;
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $_SESSION['goalCount'] += 1;

    $input['title'] = htmlentities($_POST ['title'],ENT_QUOTES);
    $input['deadline'] = htmlentities($_POST ['deadline'],ENT_QUOTES);
    $input['description'] = htmlentities($_POST['description'],ENT_QUOTES);
    convertDate($input['deadline']);

    $goal = new Goal($input['title'], $input['description'], $_SESSION['username'], $input['deadline']);
    $_SESSION['goals'][] = $goal;
                   // ^ add another dimension

} // missing closing curly brace

?>

<div class="top">
    <p>h</p>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="sixteen columns topbar">
        <?php require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/global/header.php'; ?><!-- Content Begins -->
        <div class="content">
            <h1> OO Test Page - Batch add goals</h1><hr/>
            <div class="six columns">
                <form action="" method="POST">
                    <fieldset>
                        <div>
                        <h4>Title</h4>
                            <span id='title-result'></span>
                            <label for="title"></label><br />
                            <input type="text" id="title" name="title" placeholder="e.g. Graduate" value="" required  aria-required="true">

                        </div>
                        <div>
                        <h4>Description</h4>
                        <span id='description-result'></span>
                            <label for="description"></label>


                            <textarea type="description" id="description" placeholder="e.g. with first-class honours" name="description" value="" required aria-required="true"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                        <h4>Deadline</h4>
                        <span id='description-result'></span>
                            <label for="deadline"></label>
                            <input rows="2"type="date" id="datepick" placeholder="" name="deadline" value="" required aria-required="true"/>

                        </div>

                        <div class="submit">
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add">
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>


    <div class="ten columns">
    <?php
    foreach ($_SESSION['goals'] as $goal) {
        echo '<div class="goal"><h4>'. $goal->title .'</h4>'. $goal->desc .'</h4><p>'. $goalCount .'</p></div>';
    }
    ?>
    </div>

            <!-- Content Ends -->
        <?php require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/global/footer.php'; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Sidenote: Always turn on error reporting.

Comment: It is now producing more elements in the array and capturing the information, but it wont display the subsequent objects in the array and the errors say __PHP__Incomplete_Class_Name/Object => Goal

Comment: @Phillip-Marsden are you saving an object which has methods etc? make sure your class is declared before declaration of `session_start()`

Comment: Yes it has a few methods but I am only using the constructor to set the base information I have made sure session start is called after my class is requested